# How to select a part of vector in boost c++

Tags: c++, r, matlab, boost, vector

I am having a dumb question, which I want to chop off or just select a part of vector elements.

I am using boost matrix to output a matrix of numbers, and boost has a very neat function, matrix_column<> (matrix, index) to select a column as vector in boost matrix.

Now I need to cut the selected column to two parts, and do different calculations.
I think I want a way of selecting elements like in matlab or R, ie vector(1:5), return 1 to 5 indexed vector.

Could you guys please give me some suggestions or directions? Right now I am thinking a way of copy selected part to a new vector to process my calculation, not so efficient.

Comment: inb4 someone mentions `std::valarray`... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass two iterators of the vector (like `vec.begin()` and `vec.begin() + n`)  or even a [boost:range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html)

This (pair of iterators) is the way the STL does it, you can find lots of examples [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/).